# User authentication Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have created a Website in ASP.Net MVC5 and used a login function in it, it works fine on localhost but when I uploaded the site server, 
Server redirects me to the login page on each click.

**Below is login Function**

```
public ActionResult DoLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            var user = new UserRepository().GetAll()
                                            .Where(u => u.UserName.ToUpper() == username.Trim().ToUpper()
                                                    && u.Password == password).SingleOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,true);

                var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), true, user.Roles);
                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                Session["Name"] = user.Name;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "User Name or Password is incorrect";
        return View("Login");
    }
```

then I added the below function in `Global.asax.cs` File.

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
            {
                var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);
            }
        }
    }
```

After that I have added `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` before each Controller (Not before methods in Controller) I want to Restrict access to.

Now, whenever I login, It redirects me to Index Method of Student controller, after that I click on some other link it again takes me to the Login page. Sometimes it takes me to clicked link without taking me to Login Page. Whats the Problem with my code? it works fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the auth ticket twice;

```
        if (user != null)
        {
            //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,true); Remove it
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), true, user.Roles);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            Session["Name"] = user.Name;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
        }
```

Also, I suggest you to don't store the roles in cookie because if the user role has been removed or added new one, you can't update them. So,

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
            {
                var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');//fill it from database and it could be better to use cache mechanism for performance concern
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: after following your answer and removing function from Global.asax.cs File, am being redirected to login page after entering Correct username and password.

Comment: I updated the answer. Just remove "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,true);"